# Spring Boot - How can I have different log configurations per profile?

Tags: logging, configuration, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to configure logging support per different profile in Spring Boot. This is the relevant part of the application.yml file:

```
spring:
    profiles.active: development
---
spring:
    profiles: development
logging.config: logback-development.xml
---
spring:
    profiles: test
logging.config: logback-test.xml
```

As you can see I have two profiles (development is the default one) and I'm using Logback as the logging framework. Only difference between two Logback configuration xml files is that test one is logging both to console and a file.

The problem I'm encountering is that the logback-test.xml configuration is used even if I'm using development profile. Maybe I miss-understood Spring Boot configuration, but shouldn't this configuration allow me to use different logging configuration per Spring profile?

logback-development.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>[%p] %c - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="rs.rmilovic.bookmarksmanager" level="DEBUG" />

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <root level="${logback.loglevel}">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

logback-test.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/holiday_requets.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <logger name="rs.rmilovic.bookmarksmanager" level="INFO" />

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <root level="${logback.loglevel}">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the logging.config to look in the classpath like this

```
logging:
  config: classpath:logback-development.xml
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help. It seems that it is looking on the classpath by default so that "classpath:" prefix is not necessary. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Must be something else about your config. I tested your exact config above before and after my suggestion and it resolved it. I always use classpath:* in my projects with success. Maybe post some more info. Are you using embedded server or deploying a war? Or the post the log back xml

Comment: I am using embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't overriding the profile at runtime somewhere? Can you find this line in your logging output "Activated profiles development"

Comment: This is what I've found in the created log file:
2015-06-21 02:39:59,394 DEBUG [main] ConfigFileApplicationListener: Activated profiles development

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *.yml, set it in relevant *.properties file for profile, e.g.:
in

```
application-prod.properties
```

set:

```
    logging.config=classpath:logback-prod.xml
```